# Run macro only in specific place in the word

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to change this macro so that it runs from a designated place in the word? I think I need to use bookmarks.

```
Sub rozmiar()
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
    For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
        With .InlineShapes(i)
            .Height = CentimetersToPoints(5)
            .Width = CentimetersToPoints(7)
        End With
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What's "a place in a word"? Please define.

Comment: Your thread title and post disagree about what you want to do. The title says:
«Run macro only ***in*** specific place in the word», but the post says:
«runs ***from*** a designated place in the word». Which is it?

Comment: I have a Word document, and I want to change the pictures in it from a selected place in the document